# How to change message text in JSP from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I'm javascript newbie, so excuse me :)

I've got following in my **SomePage.jsp**:

```
<div id="prompt-form" title="Some title">
  <p> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-comment" style="float:left; margin:0 8px 35px 0;"></span>

MESSAGE_TO_REPLACE

 </p>
</div>
```

And I'm using following javascript code:

```
$("#prompt-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resize: "auto",
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Yes: function () {
             if (SOME_FLAG) {
              MESSAGE_TO_REPLACE = "11"; 
             } else {
              MESSAGE_TO_REPLACE = "12";
             }

        },
        No: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    open: function () {
        $(":button:contains('No')").focus();
    }
});
```

The question is, how to send new message text from my javascript code (this file is not build in my SomePage.jsp) to SomePage.jsp ?

Is it real ?

Thanks for everyone.

Comment: either submit a form or use ajax. Not clear what behavior you are looking for

Comment: you can use $(".class-name").html("content"); , place your data inside span with any class name .

Answer (score 0):

I m not getting what you are trying to say... If you want to change text "MESSAGE_TO_REPLACE" use following code otherwise ignore it.. :)

```
   <div id="prompt-form" title="Some title">
  <p> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-comment" style="float:left; margin:0 8px 35px 0;"></span>
<span id="msgToReplace">
MESSAGE_TO_REPLACE
</span>
 </p>
</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("msgToReplace").innerHTML = "newText";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery selector to find the element which html you need to change. Then use `$.html()` to change it. The span tag should enclose the message, so you can replace the body.

**html code:**

```
<p> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-comment" style="float:left; margin:0 8px 35px 0;">

MESSAGE_TO_REPLACE

</span></p>
```

**js code:**

```js
 if (SOME_FLAG) {
     $("#prompt-form p span").html("11"); 
 } else {
     $("#prompt-form p span").html("12");
 }
```

<kbd>[Running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4yoz0h5e/3)</kbd>